# how to write a function, it will do the same thing with replace()

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, input

Can I define a function, that will do the same thing with 
`string.replace(old,new)`?

I wrote a little program:

```
word = input()


at =  "AT"

if at in word:
    new = word.replace(at,"IN")

print(new)
```

However I don't want to use the `replace()`, I want to use a custom function.

Comment: There's no practical reason to use your own replacement for `str.replace`, except if you do so as exercise and/or homework. For that purpose your question is pretty useless, because you're supposed to **implement it yourself for learning purposes**; the way this question is phrased you're not going to learn anything except how to get someone on the internet to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this :

```
def custom_replace(string, old, new):

    index = string.find(old)

    if index == -1:
        return string

    return string[:index] + new + string[index + len(old):]


string = 'Hello World !'

old = 'World'
new = 'StackOverflow'

print(custom_replace(string, old, new))
```

Which outputs :

```
Hello StackOverflow !
```

Hope it'll be helpful (and that `find` is authorized) ;)